# What's I should use "where T: <Interface>"?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-programming

What's the diferente between this code?

```
interface ICommandHanddler<T> where T : ICommand
    {
        void Handle(T command);
    }
```

and this code:

```
interface ICommandHanddler<ICommand>
    {
        void Handle(ICommand command);
    }
```

For me it's have the same impact in my software, but i wanna know if that really dont impact anything or it's just a good practice

Comment: If you don't care about `T`'s actual type, use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The former says: "Interface of type CLASS where CLASS is an extension of ICommand"
The latter says: "Interface of type ICommand"

The former allows you to call your `ICommandHanddler` interface with multiple types of objects so long as they inherit `ICommand`, or are `ICommand`.

On the impact of your program: if you have multiple classes that extend from a common parent and override the same function, it's going to make your life a lot easier and more organized to do the former method.  If you *only* have the `ICommand` class, then you're fine doing the latter.  It's all dependent on how you plan on build and extending your classes.